# How to pass the element in dojo.connect

Tags: javascript, dojo, event-handling, thumbnails, mouseover

I am creating a widget in dojo that enlarges the thumbnail on mouse over.

The widget binds the mouseover event with all thumbnails in the constructor like this:

```
dojo.connect(imgTag, "mouseover", this, "_showImgPreview");
```

In _showImgPreview() I need the image on which mouse over event occurred. By doing above I am only getting the event and not the image.

How can I get the thumbnail on which event occurred in _showImgPreview()?

I know I can do like this but I am interested in knowing how can I do it using the method mentioned above.

```
var self = this;
dojo.connect(imgTag, "mouseover", function(e){
   self._showImgPreview(e, this);
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.target` will be the imgTag.

If you are inside a class that is extending Widget, you can use

```
this.connect(imgTag, "mouseover", "_showImgPreview");
```

If you are not, you can use

```
dojo.connect(imgTag, "mouseover", dojo.hitch(this, this._showImgPreview));
```

Note: `dojo/connect` has been deprecated in favor of `dojo/on`

Comment: I am inside the class. How will I get imgTag in _showImgPreview method?

Comment: e.target  [Edited the answer to add this]